# 500 Internal Server Error: Incorrect [server-configuration]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

I found the [server-configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/server-configuration) tag on a question about nginx configuration and it appears to be a very good candidate for burnination.

Burnination criteria:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?** *No*

This tag has 173 questions (10 in 2019, 15 in 2018, ....) and it has no description.
Questions tagged with it are mainly questions about:

- web server configuration (and many tags about specific web servers exists)
- a software that runs as a server (e.g. sql)
- a software that runs on a server (e.g. wordpress)
- (real) server configuration (e.g. network configuration)

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?** *No*

Strictly speaking, server configuration is a Serverfault topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?** *No*

Since the meaning of server-configuration is broad and used with different meanings, it doesn't add any meaningful information to questions.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?** *No*

See above